# WordPress JetPack stats with non-WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, statistics

I have a number of WordPress sites and have become accustomed to the way in which it presents detailed statistics. Is it possible to utilise those statistics for a non-WordPress powered site?

I am developing a custom site using PHP but would absolutely love to use the same statistics system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Jetpack hooks your WP site with the wordpress cloud. 
If you have knowledge you can create something similiar

Comment: I feared as much. If I had some spare time I would create a custom hook into the wordpress cloud. So I guess it's time to learn Google Analytics instead... cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the new Wordpress Jetpack plugin for detailed stats like wordpress.com,  publicize  feature and more! http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/

Simply have a wordpress.com account and allow jetpack plugin in your website to connect to your wordpress account.

It supports non wordpress.com website but not a general php website.

Comment: The question asks if Wordpress stats can be used in a custom/non-wordpress site. You cannot install a wordpress plugin to a non-wordpress site.